# Does Python use NFAs for regular expression evaluation in the re module?

Tags: python, regex, nfa

Does anybody know if Python (any version) used NFAs (Non-Deterministic Finite Automata) to evaluate regular expressions or does it use some other mechanism? Please provide links/reference if available.

Comment: Since most RE engines nowadays allow for non-regular languages to be matched I doubt any modern RE engine actually still uses NFAs or DFAs anymore.

Comment: Well, since an RE engine can identify a subset of RE's that are regular, and those are in common use, it makes sense to optimize for those scenarios. So it's entirely possible that they _sometimes_ use NFA's or DFA's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NFA.

See Friedl's *Mastering Regular Expressions*, 3rd edition, chapter 4 - table 4-1, page 145.

Google books has [a preview](http://books.google.com/books?id=NYEX-Q9evKoC&pg=PA145&dq=%22table+4-1%22+mastering+regular+expressions#v=onepage&q=&f=false) to it.

Answer (score 8):

This should take less than a ms on a DFA:

```
$ time python3 -c 'import re; re.match("a?"*25+"a"*25, "a"*25)'
real    0m7.273s
```

Change 25 with 100 and it won't terminate for a lifetime.

Here is how it looks on a DFA (grep):

```
$ time echo "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" |grep "a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?a\?aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
real    0m0.063s
```

There is a great discussion of the topic at http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html